# Comparar un fichero con un Argumento

Tags: java

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
File[] ficheros2=new File(".").listFiles(new FileFilter() { 
public boolean accept(File fichero) {
return fichero.isFile();
}
});
int ocultos2=0;
int totalFicheros=0;
for(File fichero :ficheros2) {
//System.out.println(fichero.getName()); //Si queremos mostrar todas las carpetas 

// OCULTOS
if (fichero.isHidden()  ){ 
   System.out.println("L'arxiu es ocult." +args[0]);
   ocultos2++;
}  
if (!fichero.isHidden() ) { 
    System.out.println("L'arxiu es lliure"+args[0]);
  totalFicheros ++;   
}}

System.out.println("Numero de ficheros visibles "+totalFicheros);
System.out.println("Número de ficheros ocults :"+ocultos2);
```

No tengo ni idea de como comparar los ficheros con el `argumento[0]`.

Es decir 
    `if (!fichero.isHidden() ) {`

Tendria que ser algo así:

`if(!fichero.isHidden() && fichero.equals(args[0])`.

He probado con equals, ==, y mil cosas más.. pero no hay nada que me sirva.. Podéis decirme con que puedo comparararlos??

La idea del programa a modo resumen es:

```
El Filtro me saca solo los archivos. 

Si el fichero es oculto y es igual que el argumento 
......

Si el fichero es visible y es igual que el argumento
.....
```

gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu no puedes comparar directamente un `File` con un `String`(args) y esperar de recibir un resultado que te sirve para algo:
 - `File` es un descriptor para un archivo o una carpeta. 
 - `String` es una cadena de caracteres

La comparación `==` en Java comprueba si la referencia de la variable apunta al mismo objeto, eso ya no puede ser en el caso de objetos tipo `File`y `String` porque son de clases completamente diferentes. Para `String`:

```
    String foo = "foo";
    String bar = "bar";
    String foobar = foo;
    String barfoo = new String(foo);
    System.out.println(String.format("foo con foo    %s - %b", bar, foo == bar));
    System.out.println(String.format("foo con foobar %s - %b", foobar, foo == foobar));
    System.out.println(String.format("foo con barfoo %s - %b", barfoo, foo == barfoo));
    System.out.println(String.format("foo con \"foo\"  %s - %b", foo, foo == "foo"));
```

resulta en:

```
foo con foo    bar - false // <- lo esperado
foo con foobar foo - true  // <- igual, porque apuntan al mismo objeto
foo con barfoo foo - false // <- las cadenas son igual, pero el objeto no lo es
foo con "foo"  foo - true  // <- eso queda true, porque "foo" y "foo" apuntan al mismo String
```

La comparación con `.equals()` comprueba si el contenido (según definición) es equivalente entre los dos objetos. Para empezar en el caso concreto, dos objetos no pueden ser iguales si uno es de tipo `File` y el otro de tipo `String`.

Si quieres comparar algo, deberías comparar por ejemplo `file.getAbsoluteFile()` con el `String` pasado como argumento.

Comment: Si pregunto es por que no lo entiendo... es decir si lo supiera... no estaría preguntando.. xD Puedes ser un poco más preciso o con un ejemplo?

Comment: Por supuesto, voy a ser un poco más extenso en la respuesta.

Comment: Stefan no hace falta! Gracias a ti lo he conseguido utilizando la siguiente expresión:   fichero.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(args[0]) ......

Gracias por inspirarme! ;)

Comment: He buscado más información sobre el getAbsolute y luego he caido en el getName... a veces es más tonto de lo que parece pero me complico yo sola.. Me falta mucho por entender sobre archivos y argumentos.. poco a poco.